# How can I drive my competitors bankrupt?

Tags: mega-mall-story

Competing malls have been opening near my mall and stealing my residents! The first time this happened I didn't really notice the effects and then a couple months later the game informed me that the other mall went out of business and it no longer appeared near my mall. I guess my mall was just too awesome.

*Now* there's a competitor who's stealing a significant amount of residents from my mall (the customers list has a number of residents with "Using Rival Mall" overlay) and I'm completely done adding investments to my own mall (helicopter landing pad on the roof!). How do I draw those residents back and force the competing mall into bankruptcy?

Comment: Call yourself Tesco? ;/

Comment: This does not belong here. It belongs on answers.onstartups.com (this is a joke BTW)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Late-game rival malls tend to start out with instantly capturing 80% of your regulars in all three areas.  This sucks, but the counter is fairly simple:

Hold regular sales.

Aside from being a great income booster, in the later stages of the game (where you seem to be right now) you generally gain enough hearts from the sale to cover the cost, and sales = more visitors to that store = faster level gain = higher quality.

Also, if you haven't yet, spend some hearts on improving various stores.

And most importantly: During sales season, holding sales boosts your rep with each sale you're holding. Use that to ensure you have a frenzy going on -- *massive* popularity booster.

It may take a couple years, but if you keep an eye on the other store you'll notice when it starts losing customers to you.

Comment: Investments also eat lot of share of the area you invest in. (if you haven't completed all yet).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the top answer on having more sales, it really does help. Use it on stores with lower sales as more popular stores will automatically sell out on their own. On top of that, you need to have more COMBOS in your shopping mall. Once I started that, all the customers came running back to my mall!

Answer (score -1):

M8 it's easy. 
Office Area :
Invest all of the buildings including the economy
Regular Area:
Once they give you the option to stimulate the economy do it cause it will subside the shares of the rival mall
Park : 
N/A